# Use data tool in MATLAB figures to show XTickLabel as coordinates

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I need to display a bar chart in MATLAB for which the `XTick`s will be labelled by a cell array of labels. As of now I am displaying the `XTickLabel`s along the x-axis at the bottom of the figure, but as the figure has a large number of bars, I want to use the data tool such that when I select a particular bar, the corresponding `XTickLabel` should be displayed as its `X` coordinate instead of it's numeric index.

A simplistic example would be:

```
x=[1 2 3];
xd={'a','b','c'};
bar(x);
set(gca,'ylim',[0,5],'xticklabel',xd);
```

where I would want

```
X = a
Y = 1
```

to be displayed when the first bar is selected in the resultant figure.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. I am not looking to display the labels at the top of the bars by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter data cursor mode and select a bar.

Now right-click on the data point, and select "Edit Text Update Function..." from the menu.

[image]

Modify the function as follows:

```
function output_txt = myfunction(obj,event_obj)
    pos = get(event_obj, 'Position');
    lab = get(gca, 'XTickLabel');
    if isa(lab,'double')
        lab = arrayfun(@(x){num2str(x)},lab);
    end
    output_txt = {['X: ', lab{pos(1)}], ['Y: ', num2str(pos(2),4)]};
end
```

First, this gets the set of xticklabels and stores them in `lab`.

Then it checks in case they're actually doubles, rather than a cell array of strings, and converts them if necessary.

Finally it displays the text of the correct label.

Save the callback as `myfunction.m` and you should be golden:

[image]

If you want to do it programmatically, then you need to get the data cursor manager for the relevant figure. Something like this should work:

```
>> bar([1,2,3])
>> dcm = datacursormode(gcf);
>> set(dcm, 'UpdateFcn', @(a,b) {'Hello', 'World'})
```

where the third argument to `set` is a handle to the function you want to use to set the text (e.g. you might use `@myfunction` if you saved the previous function as `myfunction.m`). That gives you something like this:

[image]

Comment: Not only does it work perfectly, but I also learned something new. Thanks a ton! :)

Comment: Sorry to be a bother, but would it be possible to select the text update function from my code itself?